# How to test a budge made with rails runner with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am new to ruby on rails project, and I just created a budge program at

```
lib/tasks/foo.rb
```

using rails runner.

now I need to test this code with rspec, but I am not sure

- where to put the spec file &
- how to write spec file (since there is no option of type to select like controller)

How and Where to write a spec code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Start from scratch](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/gettingstarted). 
This will show the simple steps to using RSpec with Rails from the installation of Rails and RSpec to the writing and running of RSpec tests.

Here are some other nice blog posts about RSpec:

[Getting Started with RSpec](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-rspec)

[Ruby for Newbies: Testing with Rspec](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-testing-with-rspec--net-21297)

Also, the [official RSpec website](http://rspec.info/)

These are all simple and awesome resources that will help you understand and work with RSpec.

Comment: So you mean, there is no such things like 

    RSpec.describe RequestController, :type => :tasks do... 

and I need to write a test code out of the rails framework?
but rails_runner runs within the rails application, how can I "import" rails application itself then?

Comment: RequestSpec: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec